# PostgreSQL how to use WHERE on a subquery output?

Tags: postgresql, subquery, aggregate-functions

```
select starttime, (select count(trackid) c2 from playlistitem p1 where 
p2.radiobroadcastid = p1.radiobroadcastid) from radiobroadcast p2
```

OUTPUT:

```
Starttime               c2
2011-10-14 20:00:00.0   42
2011-10-20 20:00:00.0   43
2011-10-07 09:00:00.0   7
```

I want to only show me the MAX of the c2 column ( thats 43 here ). How do I do that when c2 isn't defined as a column?

**EDIT: should probably use a HAVING and GROUP BY clause**

```
select starttime, count(trackid) from radiobroadcast inner join playlistitem 
using(radiobroadcastid) GROUP by starttime HAVING count(*) > 100
```

Anyway to only show MAX value as boolean for count in HAVING?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the result of the sub-query an alias, then you can order by that alias and apply a limit:

```
select starttime, 
        (select count(trackid)
         from playlistitem p1 
         where p2.radiobroadcastid = p1.radiobroadcastid) as c2
from radiobroadcast p2 
order by c2 desc
limit 1;
```

Note that if you have two rows with the same count, you would still only see one using this approach.

To find the highest value using the JOIN statement, use the same approach:

```
select starttime, 
       count(trackid) as cnt
from radiobroadcast 
  join playlistitem using(radiobroadcastid) 
GROUP by starttime 
order by cnt desc
limit 1;
```

If you have to consider multiple highest counts and what to see all of them, you can use a window function to obtain the highest count, but you need to wrap the query in a derived table in order to use the alias:

```
select starttime, cnt
from (
    select starttime, 
           count(trackid) as cnt,
           max(count(trackid)) over () as max_cnt
    from radiobroadcast 
      join playlistitem using(radiobroadcastid) 
    GROUP by starttime 
) t
where cnt = max_cnt;
```

If you only need a single row, the `LIMIT` approach is typically faster then the one using a window function.

Comment: Even with an alias I get ´org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "c2" does not exist` when I use WHERE. (Order by works)

Comment: @RobVanMeirvenne: correct, you can use an alias like that only in the order by clause. But with an `order by` and `limit` you don't need the where clause

Comment: **select starttime, count(trackid) from radiobroadcast inner join playlistitem using(radiobroadcastid) GROUP by starttime HAVING count(*) > 100**                        This code now displays all Starttimes with an amount greater than 100. Do you know how I can select the Maximum amount only now? My class did a very bad explanation on this.

Comment: @RobVanMeirvenne: same approach: `order by desc` and `limit`

Comment: I'm not allowed to use that, I have to do it with HAVING. Thanks anyways :)